# Get content from xml file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have this code below which loads xml file from url

> Question How can I get the data from it and use a foreach loop to display the content;

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $url = "http://xml.someurl.nz/schedule?token=mytoken";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($xml);
        echo "</pre>";

        foreach ($xml['meetings'] as $race) {
            echo $race['metting'];
        }


        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

It prints out below like

```
<schedule date="2018-03-01">
<meetings>
    <meeting>
        <betslip_type>STD</betslip_type>
        <code>WAKG</code>
        <country>nzl</country>
        <date>2018-03-01</date>
        <name>Cambridge Dogs</name>
        <number>3</number>
        <nz>1</nz>
        <status>CL</status>
        <type>GR</type>
        <venue>Cambridge</venue>
        <races>
        <race>
        <class>C0</class>
        <length>375</length>
        <name>WELCOME TO CAMBRIDGE RACEWAY SPRINT</name>
        <norm_time>2018-03-01 12:00:00</norm_time>
        <number>1</number>
        <stake>$1,365.00</stake>
        <status>CL</status>
        <track>GOOD</track>
        <weather>OVERCAST</weather>
        <options>
        <option>
        <number>301</number>
        <type>FFWIN</type>
        </option>
        <option>
        <number>1301</number>
        <type>FFPLC</type>
        </option>
        </options>
        <entries>

        <entry>
        <name>Phuket Paul</name>
        <number>1</number>
        <scratched>0</scratched>
        </entry>

        <entry>
        <name>Jetsun Paint</name>
        <number>2</number>
        <scratched>1</scratched>
        </entry>

        <entry>
        <name>Bigtime Wayno</name>
        <number>3</number>
        <scratched>0</scratched>
        </entry>

        <entry>
        <name>Feed The Need</name>
        <number>4</number>
        <scratched>0</scratched>
        </entry>

        <entry>
        <name>Jetsun Woody</name>
        <number>5</number>
        <scratched>1</scratched>
        </entry>

        <entry>
        <name>Snoopy's Bro</name>
        <number>6</number>
        <scratched>0</scratched>
        </entry>

        <entry>
        <name>Crackling</name>
        <number>7</number>
        <scratched>0</scratched>
        </entry>

        <entry>
        <name>Jinja Lad</name>
        <number>8</number>
        <scratched>0</scratched>
        </entry>

        <entry>
        <barrier>2</barrier>
        <name>Blitzem Gem</name>
        <number>9</number>
        <scratched>0</scratched>
        </entry>

        </entries>
        </race>
    <meeting>
<meetings>
</schedule>
```

Comment: `races` closing node forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml   = simplexml_load_string($url);
$json  = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

for json output -> echo $json;
   for php array   -> print_r($array);

eg: -

```
foreach($array as $value) {
   echo $value['metting'];
}
```

Comment: I all ready print_r but just can get the foreach loop to work

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out now I had to do a foreach loop with in a foreach loop

```
public function index()
{

    $url = "http://xml.someurl.co.nz/schedule?token=sometoken";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    echo "<pre>";


    foreach ($xml as $key) {

        foreach ($key->meeting as $value) {
            echo "$value->betslip_type";
        }
    }

    echo "</pre>";

    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all your XML is not valid please validate your XML then you can use foreach.

[XML VALIDATOR](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator)

```
<schedule date="2018-03-01">
<meetings>
    <meeting>
        <betslip_type>STD</betslip_type>
        <code>WAKG</code>
        <country>nzl</country>
        <date>2018-03-01</date>
        <name>Cambridge Dogs</name>
        <number>3</number>
        <nz>1</nz>
        <status>CL</status>
        <type>GR</type>
        <venue>Cambridge</venue>
        <races>
            <race>
                <class>C0</class>
                <length>375</length>
                <name>WELCOME TO CAMBRIDGE RACEWAY SPRINT</name>
                <norm_time>2018-03-01 12:00:00</norm_time>
                <number>1</number>
                <stake>$1,365.00</stake>
                <status>CL</status>
                <track>GOOD</track>
                <weather>OVERCAST</weather>
                <options>
                    <option>
                        <number>301</number>
                        <type>FFWIN</type>
                    </option>
                    <option>
                        <number>1301</number>
                        <type>FFPLC</type>
                    </option>
                </options>
                <entries>
                    <entry>
                        <name>Phuket Paul</name>
                        <number>1</number>
                        <scratched>0</scratched>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <name>Jetsun Paint</name>
                        <number>2</number>
                        <scratched>1</scratched>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <name>Bigtime Wayno</name>
                        <number>3</number>
                        <scratched>0</scratched>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <name>Feed The Need</name>
                        <number>4</number>
                        <scratched>0</scratched>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <name>Jetsun Woody</name>
                        <number>5</number>
                        <scratched>1</scratched>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <name>Snoopy's Bro</name>
                        <number>6</number>
                        <scratched>0</scratched>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <name>Crackling</name>
                        <number>7</number>
                        <scratched>0</scratched>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <name>Jinja Lad</name>
                        <number>8</number>
                        <scratched>0</scratched>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <barrier>2</barrier>
                        <name>Blitzem Gem</name>
                        <number>9</number>
                        <scratched>0</scratched>
                    </entry>
                </entries>
            </race>
        </races>
    </meeting>
</meetings>
```

now you can use foreach or what ever you want to use

```
$xml   = simplexml_load_string($XML);
$json  = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

print_r($array);
```

**YOU CANNOT USE  ' single quote in XML VALUE  LIKE THIS**

```
 <name>Snoopy's Bro</name>
```

Comment: I know the xml is not valid I hid the token and url for security

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper function like....

```
<?php
function loadXML()
{
    if(file_exists('xml_load/test.xml')) 
    {
      $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml_load/test.xml');
    } 
    else 
    {
        exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
    }
?>
<?php
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load("xml_load/test.xml");
    $node_list = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('userrole');
    echo "<select name='con' class='popup_dd'>";
    echo "<option value=''> Select Role</option>";
    foreach($node_list AS $node)
    {
        $cur1 = $node->getElementsByTagName("uservalue");
        $cur = $node->getElementsByTagName("name");
        $v_cur = $cur->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $v_cur1 = $cur1->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo "<option value=".$v_cur1.">". $v_cur. "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

?>

And use this in view file `<?php loadXML(); ?>`

But make sure, you need to add helper file in autoload.php.

$autoload['helper'] = array('helpername');